# Missing ports on macOS in ipv6

Tags: networking, macos, ipv6, ipv4

I would like to understand how it is possible to have a number of different ports between my local ip v4 and v6.

I have a NodeJS service running on port `57110` but I can't see it on my IP v6. How is this possible?

Below are two screenshots that show my ports status via nmap scan :

nmap of ports 127.0.0.1 and ::1

[image: nmap of ports 127.0.0.1 and ::1]

diff between the two nmaps

[image: diff between the two nmaps]

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots when text is better. Your first screenshot, “nmap of ports 127.0.0.1 and ::1” should just be text in your question.\

Comment: Why do you think that for every IPv4 port there should be a matching IPv6 port? You've found that there are many more IPv4 listeners than IPv6.

Comment: applications choose to bind to a given interface\address, so its up to the software to decide if it wants to listen on IPv6. you may find that you can reconfigure some of those applications to work on IPv6 or both protocols, but some will likely fixate on IPv4, and only the software maker could change that.